# Android , ContactsContract.Groups query crash

Tags: java, android, sql

Here I am using this code for retrieving all groups from android phone.
Unfortunately I am getting crash on some android phones e.g.

Android 5.0.0
Nexus 5 (hammerhead)

ERROR:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

at this line :

```
final int IDX_ID = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID);
```

Here is my code :

```
public void loadGroups() {

    if (groupsV.size()==0){

        final String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {

        ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES,ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE};

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI,GROUP_PROJECTION,ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED+"!='1' AND "+ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE+"!='0' ",null,null);

        final int IDX_ID = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID);
        final int IDX_TITLE = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {        
            c.getString(IDX_ID);
            c.getString(IDX_TITLE);

           int users = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES));

           String groupType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE));

        if (users > 0 && groupType.equals("vnd.sec.contact.phone")){

          String group = c.getString(IDX_ID)+","+c.getString(IDX_TITLE)+","+users;

           groupsV.add(group);
        }
    }

   c.close();
 }
}
```

How can I fix this please ? Thanks !

Comment: `c` is null, check that

Comment: As @shayanpourvatan indicates, you have to find out why `c` is `null`. Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: you mean to put it in try catch ? maybe there is another new quary that can fix this error ?

Comment: I think its null cuz this android device not supports this kind of query |:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you are making on the ContactsContract.Groups above might not be returning any data on some of the phones. This looks like a case of NullPointerException not being handled correctly.